# Problem submitting file content in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jform

Im submitting my file through jquery by using Jform.js plugin and its working in Firefox but when i try it on IE8 file properly sumbitted but file upload control gets hidden and further more when i comment IE condition then the file upload control doesnt get hide but when i check Request.Files[0].ContentLength in my controller it have 0 value. This is my code and what may be im doing wrong? Im using Asp.net MVC and jquery-1.4.2

```
        var myform = document.createElement("form");    
        myform.style.display = "none"
        myform.action = "/Media/AjaxSubmit";
        myform.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
        myform.method = "post";
        var imageLoad;
        var imageLoadParent;
        if (document.all) {//IE
            imageLoad = document.getElementById(fileId);
            imageLoadParent = document.getElementById(fileId).parentNode;
            myform.appendChild(imageLoad);
            document.body.appendChild(myform);
        }
        else {//FF          
                imageLoad = document.getElementById(fileId).cloneNode(true);
                myform.appendChild(imageLoad);
                document.body.appendChild(myform);          
        }    
        $(myform).ajaxSubmit({ success: function (responseText) {    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simple i just add that browse control when it response back from ajaxsubmit function and code is as follows

```
            $(myform).ajaxSubmit({ success: function (responseText) {
            if (document.all) {//IE
                imageLoadParent.appendChild(myform.firstChild);
            }
            else//FF                     
            {
                document.body.removeChild(myform);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the delirium before `.ajaxSubmit`? It looks like code from the end of the 90s. I would recommend you to simply use jQuery and not worry about cross browser issues:

```
$('form')
    .attr('action', '/Media/AjaxSubmit')
    .attr('method', 'post')
    .attr('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')
    .hide()
    .append($('#' + fileId).clone())
    .ajaxSubmit({
        success: function(responseText) {
            // ...
        }
    })
    .appendTo('body');
```

Remark: the hardcoded form action looks ugly. You should consider using HTML helpers to generate urls.

Comment: Thanks Darin but the issue is still remains when i remove clone() function file submits correctly but the file uploader get hides and if i use the same code that you have provided then on AjaxSubmit function i recieved 0 in Request.Files[0].ContentLength